# Filter the HTML content of plugin

Tags: plugins, filters

I am using the [Marketpress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-ecommerce/) plugin. I want to modify `single_order_funct()` function HTML content in it. I want to make changes so that, when it is updated, I don't lose them.

```
class PluginClass{
 function single_order_funct() {
?>
   <h1>test</h1>
<?php
}

function orders_funct() {
 if (isset($_GET['order_id'])) {
    $this->single_order_funct();
    return;
 }
}
```

Whenever `single_order_funct()` function is called, I want to modify the HTML content it returns. How can I do it with `remove_action()` and `add_action()` or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include the function definition for `single_order_funct()`.

Comment: @ChipBennett The `single_order_funct()` definition is there.

Comment: single_order_funct() is available in the code i provided

Comment: MarketPress has a support forum. Have you already asked there?

Comment: How is that code used? It doesn't use any hooks internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the output filterable, you simply need to define a *custom filter*, and pass the output through it.

Your function outputs (echoes) this value:

```
<h1>test</h1>
```

If you want it to be *filterable*, you need to put that output in a PHP string. Instead of this:

```
?>
    <h1>test</h1>
<?php
```

Do something like this:

```
$output = '<h1>test</h1>';
```

Then `echo` it:

```
// Define
$output = '<h1>test</h1>';
// Output
echo $output;
```

Now, you have something that you can pass through a *custom filter*, which you would define using [`apply_filters()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters):

```
apply_filters( $filter_name, $value );
```

Let's call this filter `wpse140953_order_funct`:

```
// Define
$output = '<h1>test</h1>';
// Output
echo apply_filters( 'wpse140953_order_funct', $output );
```

...and that's it. Now the output is filterable.